# Downloaded JDCB driver through Intellij Ultimate not applying in the code? Must import dependancy separately

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, driver

I have Intellij Ultimate thanks to my university, and one takeaway is the easy installation of database drivers through the Database interface. I am, however, trying to access "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" in my code and it does not find it? So far I have been importing the same JAR file as a dependancy but I thought all this should have been taken care of automatically?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java JDBCTest <user> <password>");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String user = args[0]; // username
        String pwd = args[1]; // password 
        System.out.println(user + ", *********");
        String database = "Company"; // the name of the specific database 
        String server
                = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + database
                + "?UseClientEnc=UTF8";

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pwd);
            System.out.println("Connected!");

            executeQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM T_Employee");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                    System.out.println("Connection closed.");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void executeQuery(Connection con, String query) throws SQLException {

        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            // Execute the SQL statement
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            // Get the attribute names
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int ccount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int c = 1; c <= ccount; c++) {
                System.out.print(metaData.getColumnName(c) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();

            // Get the attribute values
            while (rs.next()) {
                // NB! This is an example, -not- the preferred way to retrieve data.
                // You should use methods that return a specific data type, like
                // rs.getInt(), rs.getString() or such.
                // It's also advisable to store each tuple (row) in an object of
                // custom type (e.g. Employee).
                for (int c = 1; c <= ccount; c++) {
                    System.out.print(rs.getObject(c) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should be looking at generic build techniques like Maven. It's not going to help in the long run to be using IDE-specific features (which evidently aren't working for you anyway). Learn how the dependencies work in Maven - you should be able to make a Maven project with IntelliJ. Also, driver classes no longer need to be loaded dynamically. Use `DriverManager.getConnection`

Comment: This is a Maven project (also using JavaFX), however, I'm not yet entirely sure what exactly Maven is or does.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the default type of project I'd guess. So I'd look at your pom.xml file, find out how it works and make sure the driver dependency is in there. Also, treat your `Connection` with try-with-resources as in other parts of your code. It will be a lot cleaner and tighter

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on maven. [The official "Maven in 5 Minutes" tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) is a good start. Keep in mind that maven is quite complex, so do not expect to learn everything about maven in an afternoon.

Comment: Absolutely right. You will be able to learn enough though in a few minutes to shed light on your current dependency problem. Try to use the command line for Maven in time too, as well as your IDE